# what does slab_bufclt() in slab_get_obj() mean?

Tags: c, linux, memory, kernel, alloc

In Linux kernel, we have a function in mm/slab.c

```
static void *slab_get_obj(struct kmem_cache *cachep, struct slab
*slabp,
                                int nodeid) {
        void *objp = index_to_obj(cachep, slabp, slabp->free);
        kmem_bufctl_t next;

        slabp->inuse++;
        next = slab_bufctl(slabp)[slabp->free];
#if DEBUG
        slab_bufctl(slabp)[slabp->free] = BUFCTL_FREE;
        WARN_ON(slabp->nodeid != nodeid);
#endif
        slabp->free = next;

        return objp; }
```

Where,

```
static inline kmem_bufctl_t *slab_bufctl(struct slab *slabp)
{
        return (kmem_bufctl_t *) (slabp + 1);
}
```

I don't understand what slab_bufctl() does or how it finds the next free slab with it.

Comment: It seems like `struct slab *slabp` is an array of `struct slab`. Hence, `(slabp + 1)` in `slab_bufctl` just returns the element next to `slabp`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `struct slab *slabp` is an array of `struct slab`. Hence, `(slabp + 1)` in `slab_bufctl()` just returns the element next to `slabp`.

In addition, since `slab_bufctl()` returns the element as `kmem_bufctl_t *`, which is later accessed as an array, I think we can have a loose definition of `struct slab` as follows:

```
struct slab {
    kmem_bufctl_t *_name;
}
```